# Suppressing logs in scala?

Tags: scala, akka, couchbase

I have a scala project that uses akka-http.  It is connected to a couchbase database and I want to be able to suppress some of the logs showing up in the terminal such as :

```
16:52:00.970 [cb-computations-1] DEBUG com.couchbase.client.core.node.Node - [127.0.0.1/localhost]: Adding Service VIEW
```

My application.conf looks like this:

```
akka {
  log-config-on-start = off
  stdout-loglevel = INFO
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  default-dispatcher {
    fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-min = 8
    }
  }
  test {
    timefactor = 1
  }
}


http {
  host = "0.0.0.0"
  host = ${?HOST}
  port = 4000
  port = ${?PORT}
}
```

I've tried changing it but nothing works!

Comment: What is your logging backend (no slf4j is not a backend)? Logback? If so the should be logback.xml where you can define root logger level as well as specific logger level.